# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x708d31bd64 in tid 22188

Tags: android

Hi guys I don't have much Android experience but I've been given a task that I'm quite stumped on. I'm getting the error

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x708d31bd64 in tid 22188
```

This happens when I try to install my app on to a `Galaxy Note 9` running on `Android 10`. I'm using `Android Studio 4.1 R3`. I've been searching for answers all day and the closest I've come is from `https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29517`.

From what I gather, this error is only for Android 10 and above, and that I need to disable `Execute Memory Only (XOM)` or use `mprotect()` somewhere. As indicated in `https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/execute-only-memory#disabling`, I need to do either one of the following:

```
// Android.mk
LOCAL_XOM := false

// Android.bp
cc_binary { // or other module types
   ...
   xom: false,
}
```

My question is then where are `Android.mk` and `Android.bp`? I'm not able to find either files in my project.

OR

```
If code introspection is necessary on executable code sections, first call mprotect to mark the code readable. Then after the operation is complete, call mprotect again to mark it unreadable.
```

How exactly do you use `mprotect()`? I'm not able to find any clear examples showing its usage.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I can't confirm the solution implemented solves my problem yet (still being tested in QA) but for me I believe it was because Android 10 has some issues with Arm64 based phones. I was using an old version of Twilio (3.1.x) and I believe that caused the memory error. It got upgraded to 6.1.x so hopefully that fixes it. I'll post what I found below to help you narrow down to the source of the error.

Comment: Updating form Twilio 3.1.x to 6.1.x fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 6):

Android 10 seems to have problems with Arm64 based architecture. Which give you `Execute-only memory violation` for some libraries. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash

You can find out more details about the root of the problem (the library that's giving the issue) with:

Use the Android Debugger to get a crash dump.

1. On the Android device navigate to `Settings > Developer options > enable USB debugging`
2. Connect the Android device to computer with USB
3. Download the Android SDK Platform Tools: `Android Studio > Tools> SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Android SDK Platform-Tools`
4. If on windows navigate to - `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

   If on mac navigate to `/Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`
5. Run the App and crash the app
6. From the terminal run: `./adb logcat -v threadtime -d > /path_to_random_text_file_for_crash_dump/test.txt`

A more detailed error should be in the `test.txt`.

Again I cannot confirm that this will help solve your problem but that's what has helped me. For me I believe it was Twilio running on an old version, 3.1.x instead of the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when running a React Native app from Android Studio without running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in my terminal first. It was a pretty random/obscure error and took me a little while to realize this was the issue (React Native 0.66.5).

A similar error also shows if you forgot to start Metro e.g. `npx react-native start`.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the issue was in the bindingcontext's Class.

Just avoid to use custom Class that will melt with other Classes and mix the spaghetti for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, i am using flutter, the error occurs when a plugin tries to show Text from String with HTML Format and read `<table>` tag which is not supported by plugin.